# I'm in 8th grade and just finished Algebra 2. What math would I do for the next 4 years?

Tags: secondary-education, algebra

I'm in 8th grade and just finished Algebra 2. What math would I do for the next 2 years? In what order would math I would do in 9th, 10th, 11th, and 12th grade. Thanks!

Comment: *(This appears to be U.S. based.)* This will depend on what the offerings are at the high school you plan to attend next year (or 9th grade, at least; some middle schools include the 9th grade). What have other students at your school taken after Algebra 2 in the 8th grade, or are you the only such person in the last few years and thus you don't know any others? What does your math teacher (or other math teachers at your school) suggest? If you haven't asked them, why not?

Comment: Ok I will ask my math teacher!

Comment: Luke, probably the best thing for you to learn from posting here is that the world is very large. There is no big standards body that decides what happens in "9th grade" worldwide; most people wouldn't even know what "9th grade" means specifically. Similarly the term "Algebra 2" will be unclear to many people. Cheers!

Comment: By the way, if you *haven't* taken a high school level geometry course, then that would be the next logical step. However, you could probably do this while studying precalculus, since there is little specific geometry knowledge needed for precalculus. By "high school geometry", I'm excluding basic formulas for the area of a circle, volume of a sphere, etc.—I'm assuming these are things you either know or you know the existence of (and thus can look up as needed).

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that that everybody has different names for classes and curriculums. I live in the US and have done geometry. I guess I'm going to pre calculus and calculus next. Is that as hard as people say?

Comment: With the mandatory stuff out of the way, you will be able to go deeper and wider. Did you have proofs in the geometry course? How many theorems required proofs? Did you solve quadratic equations algebraically or using something like Desmos or graphing calculator? Did you solve a bunch of word problems? Improve what you already know and take what you can get: statistics, probability theory, calculus, maybe linear algebra. Don't forget to take physics, it works hand in hand with algebra, trig, calculus and geometry.

Comment: I went to school in the US and finished calculus early.  I was able to take linear algebra and calculus two in a local college.

Answer (score 2):

If you have finished Algebra 2 in November of 8th grade, you are probably very good at math. You may want to explore options outside of your school. (When I was in high school, I did not get good counseling regarding math.)

There is a wonderful online organization called [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=aops_brand&cmid=1419410580&agid=54779698534&search_keyword=art%20of%20problem%20solving&search_type=b&netid=g&adid=272880760302&adpos=&dvt=&ptid=&gclid=CjwKCAiA4o79BRBvEiwAjteoYNa_P0t7tH1vJ1HHfjZpPsqqHi0X0Kzwnmz0Fo25HGmbBLeqX5avihoCsb4QAvD_BwE). A class of theirs that you might enjoy that would not be found in high schools is Number Theory. But check out all of their courses, and see what you think. (They are not free, but they do very good work.)

If you'd like to learn more about calculus before you hit that course (and it doesn't have to be terribly hard, depends on the textbook and the teacher and the student), you might want to check out a short book by W.W. Sawyer, *What is Calculus About?*